# Cannot send `torch.tensor`s larger than approx. 64MB through `multiprocessing.Pipe()`

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, size, limit

when I try to send a `torch.tensor` through a `multiprocessing.Pipe()` I realized there is a sharp sendable limit of tensor size at approx. 64MB. If I only increase this limit by one more element the `pipe_connection.send(tensor)` fails with `Process finished with exit code 135 (interrupted by signal 7: SIGEMT)`, see detailed code below. As `Pipe`s are implemented in `Queue`s, `Pool`s etc., this limit causes problems throughout the complete `multiprocessing` module when working with larger objects.

### Questions:

- **Is this issue reproducible on other systems?**
- **Can I increase the approx. 64MB limit somehow?** I want to work with 200MB+ objects.

I realized this while using `multiprocessing.Pool().map_async()` where it does not fail but just gets stuck on the `Pool()._outqueue.put()` internal call without exception.`Pipe` again builds on `multiprocessing.reduction.ForkingPickler` and `socket.socketpair()`, but I couldn't find any limitations there either. The exact limit does depend slightly on other python kernels running in the background. Still I have 64GB memory and we're talking of 64MB objects...

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import torch


def generate_ones_tensor(num_dims):
    print('ONES: generating torch.ones() of shape = ({},)'.format(num_dims))
    ones = torch.ones(size=(num_dims,), dtype=torch.int64)
    print('ONES: torch.ones(size=({},)) generated of approx, size = {}MB'.format(num_dims,
        float((8 * num_dims / (1024 ** 2))).__round__(6)))
    return ones

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Maximum shape of torch tensor that WILL be send through a pipe
    num_max_dims = 838784
    max_ones = generate_ones_tensor(num_dims=num_max_dims)
    # Minimum shape of torch tensor that WON'T be send through a pipe
    num_too_many_dims = 8387585
    over_max_ones = generate_ones_tensor(num_dims=num_too_many_dims)

    # Create pipe with connections
    p1, p2 = mp.Pipe()

    # Sending max. byte size
    p1.send(max_ones)
    print('max_ones was send.')
    getted_max_ones = p2.recv()
    print('max_ones was received.')
    # Sending too many bytes
    p1.send(over_max_ones)
    print('over_max_ones was send.')
    getted_over_max_ones = p2.recv()
    print('over_max_ones was received.')
```

Generating output:

```py
Connected to pydev debugger (build 191.7479.30)
ONES: generating torch.ones() of shape = (838784,)
ONES: torch.ones(size=(838784,)) generated of approx, size = 6.399414MB
ONES: generating torch.ones() of shape = (8387585,)
ONES: torch.ones(size=(8387585,)) generated of approx, size = 63.992195MB
max_ones was send.
max_ones was received.

Process finished with exit code 135 (interrupted by signal 7: SIGEMT)
```

### EDIT-ATTACHMENT:

I tried to circumvent the issue by chunking my tensors in the process `Pool().starmap_async()` calculations to a size of 21MB. The chunked tensors are stored by the `AsyncResult` instance in a temp file. But atfer 3 tensors it throws a `RuntimeError`:

```py
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-1] starting listener and thread for sending handles
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] created temp directory /tmp/pymp-p9qf5b6r
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-4] CONVERTER: converting datasets['train']['input_ids'] from list to tensor
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-5] CONVERTER: pad dataset['train']['input_ids'] to length = 285
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-2] CONVERTER: generated tensor with tensor.shape = torch.Size([5000, 2, 285]) and size = 21.74MB
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-2] starting listener and thread for sending handles
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] created temp directory /tmp/pymp-ubm3dwnp
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-5] CONVERTER: converting datasets['train']['input_ids'] from list to tensor
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-6] CONVERTER: pad dataset['train']['input_ids'] to length = 285
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-3] CONVERTER: generated tensor with tensor.shape = torch.Size([5000, 2, 285]) and size = 21.74MB
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-6] CONVERTER: converting datasets['train']['input_ids'] from list to tensor
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-7] CONVERTER: pad dataset['train']['input_ids'] to length = 285
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-4] CONVERTER: generated tensor with tensor.shape = torch.Size([5000, 2, 285]) and size = 21.74MB
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-4] Possible encoding error while sending result: Error sending result: '[tensor([[[40478,   547,  1999,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
         [40478,   547,  1999,  ...,     0,     0,     0]],

        [[40478,   547,  1999,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
         [40478,   547,  1999,  ...,     0,     0,     0]],

        [[40478,   547,  1999,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
         [40478,   547,  1999,  ...,     0,     0,     0]],

        ...,

        [[40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
         [40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0]],

        [[40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
         [40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0]],

        [[40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
         [40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0]]])]'. Reason: 'RuntimeError('unable to write to file </torch_329_1813456617>',)'
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-7] CONVERTER: converting datasets['train']['input_ids'] from list to tensor
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-5] CONVERTER: generated tensor with tensor.shape = torch.Size([5000, 2, 285]) and size = 21.74MB
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-5] Possible encoding error while sending result: Error sending result: '[tensor([[[40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
         [40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0]],

        [[40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
         [40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0]],

        [[40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
         [40478,   547,  3898,  ...,     0,     0,     0]],

        ...,
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my system.  Ubuntu 18.04 here.
ONES: generating torch.ones() of shape = (838784,)
ONES: torch.ones(size=(838784,)) generated of approx, size = 6.399414MB
ONES: generating torch.ones() of shape = (8387585,)
ONES: torch.ones(size=(8387585,)) generated of approx, size = 63.992195MB
max_ones was send.
max_ones was received.
over_max_ones was send.
over_max_ones was received.

Comment: Thanks @Fabrizio for checking! The limit also varied slightly on my system depending on the background processes, plus i"m working in a docker container. Could you quickly check what happens, when you increase the shape by a factor of 2, 10, 100? That would help me a lot if my issue is system related...

Comment: I had to shorten the output but I think it's still clear:
ONES: torch.ones(size=(83875850,)) generated of approx, size = 639.9MB
over_max_ones was received.
Execution time: 2 sec

ONES: torch.ones(size=(838758500,)) generated of approx, size = 6399.2MB
over_max_ones was received.
Execution time: 6 sec

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @Fabrizio! I am still having the effect on my system for large `torch.tensor`s but I found a workaround by `pickle.dumps()` the files to a binary python object before sending it through the `Pipe()`. The `multiporcessing.Pool().map_async()` I am using for generating large tensors is not getting stuck anymore with binary objects as mentioned above... I will keep an eye on this when running the code on a cloud or other systems... THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Workaround

Thanks to @Fabrizio the issue could be identified as system specific and not reproducible on another system. For anybody who may still experiences the same problem an easy workaround is to convert the tensor to a binary python object with e.g. `pickle.dumps(tensor)` before sending it through a pipe or pickling the return of the target `func` in `Pool().map_async()`:

```py
import pickle

def target_func(*args, **kwargs):
    # calculated your results
    result = do_your_stuff(...)
    return pickle.dumps(result)
```

Let me know if you are confronted with the same issue...